# How to capture fastcgi logs and output in lighttpd

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

It seems after lighttpd internally spawns fastcgi, the output and error messages of my fastcgi app are redirected to /dev/null and lost.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a possible way to capture them in some file, while fastcgi is internally spawned ?
2. if yes how to rotate the log file daily.

Answer (score 0):

solved my issue.
I redirected the output to the default log file and then rotated the file using the logrotate utility.